# vue-cli is bloating my app: it creates a lot of files for a simple project

Tags: vue.js

I'm programming a *simple* app in vue.js with basic CRUD functionalities. Although I'm in love with this framework, it seems to me that vue-CLI is so bloated, I mean, for a simple component development it has generated more than 20k files! I know you can deploy after a compact version, but I would like to keep the project small in development time (easily sync and share with others). I'm pretty sure that a lot of these files are not been using anywhere. I wonder if vue-CLI can be configured to generate the minimum amount of files possible? or should I drop it and use vue.js directly with script import?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure most of the files you are talking about is in the `node_modules` directory. It's just dependencies of not only Vue CLI but mainly of Webpack, which is used to build your project.

This directory **should not** be shared as anyone working on the project can easily recreate it by running `npm install` - so it's usually added into `.gitignores` file (if using git)

If you are beginner with Vue I strongly recommend using CLI...